# Add Extra Tab in Products Storefront UI - Opencart v3

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I'm attempting to add another tab in addition to the `Reviews` and `Description` to the default opencart v3 default products.

Demo here to help clarify

`https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=41`

I've found little documentation on this new version of opencart, so I'm hoping to find out what files I need to modify in order to do this.

So far I'm sure of

`/store/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.twig`

What other files will I need to modify in order to to add an extra tab?

Comment: Extra tab means?

Comment: You will need to edit the `Controller` , `Model` & `Language` file for `Products` too.

Comment: i would suggest you to do any modification using ocmod file only, because it does not modify any of your original files, so you can update opencart in future without losing your code. If you directly modify original files then you virtually lost option to update opencart, as all files will be replaced by new files and your functionality will not be there anymore. Go though this https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System